# Proving that $\DeclareMathOperator{\Re}{Re}\DeclareMathOperator{\Im}{Im}|e^{z^2}| = e^{(\Re z)^2-(\Im z)^2}$

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers

I want to show that: $|e^{z^2}| = e^{(\Re z)^2-(\Im z)^2}$.

$|e^{z^2}| = |e^{(x+iy)^2}| = |e^{x^2+2xiy+(iy)^2}| = |e^{x^2+2xiy+i^2y^2}| = |e^{x^2-y^2+i2xy}| = |e^{x^2-y^2}| = e^{(\Re z)^2-(\Im z)^2}$.

Using $i^2 = - 1$ and |$e^{ix}| = 1$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. The key here is $|e^{i2xy}|=1$. Note that you could start by observing that $$|e^{a+bi}|=e^a$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you did is correct.
$$z^2 = (x + iy)^2 = x^2 - y^2 + 2xy i$$
Then
$$e^{z^2} = e^{ x^2 - y^2 + 2xy i} = e^{x^2 - y^2}.e^{2xyi}$$
So
$$\vert e^{z^2} \vert = \vert e^{x^2 - y^2}\vert .\vert e^{2xyi}\vert $$
But 
$$\vert e^{2xyi}\vert =1$$
So
$$\vert e^{z^2} \vert = \vert e^{x^2 - y^2}\vert. $$
But $$  e^{x^2 - y^2} \in \mathcal{R}^+$$
So
$$\vert e^{z^2} \vert =  e^{x^2 - y^2} $$
where $x = Re(z)$ and $y = Im(z)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is correct indeed from here we have

$$|e^{x^2+2xiy+i^2y^2}| = |e^{x^2-y^2}||e^{i2xy}|=|e^{x^2-y^2}|$$

since $\forall \theta$ we have $|e^{i\theta}|=1$.